# Grabbing Multiple Substrings Between Specific Characters in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to extract the four digit number between the last "-" and last "," into its own column. And then I want to extract the month and year into two more columns.

Below is an example of the data I get from the column that I want to push out into 3 additional columns:

"Captured Credit Card: Visa, xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1234, 12/20. Set as Default."

I want the output to be:

CC: 1234
Month: 12
Year: 20

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: What SQL product are you using: Oracle, DB2, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this using `REVERSE()` to flip the string then used `CHARINDEX()` to find the char location from the end of the string.

Then, using `LEN()` and a subtraction, the position of the last char is where it would be located in the original (un-flipped) string.

```
DECLARE @temp varchar(1000) = 'Captured Credit Card: Visa, xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1234, 12/20. Set as Default.'

SELECT 'CC: '
      + SUBSTRING(@temp
                 , LEN(@temp) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@temp), 0) + 2
                 , LEN(@temp) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@temp), 0) --find the last ','
                  -(LEN(@temp) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@temp), 0)) --find the last '-')
                  -1
                )
      + ' Month: '
      + SUBSTRING(@temp, CHARINDEX('/', @temp, 0) -2, 2)
      + ' Year: '
      + SUBSTRING(@temp, CHARINDEX('/', @temp, 0) + 1, 2)
      AS [output]
```

I had to add or subtract 1 or 2 for the correct index used in the functions.

Produces Output:

```
output
------
CC: 1234 Month: 12 Year: 20
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! This does exactly what I need to do!

Answer (score 0):

If your string is going to be in a consistent format as above then try below.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Captured Credit Card: Visa, xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1234, 12/20. Set as Default.'

SELECT Column1 = 'CC:' + RIGHT(REPLACE(@string, RIGHT(@string, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@string))),''), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(REPLACE(@string, RIGHT(@string, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@string))),''))) -1),
    Column2 = 'Month: ' + SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('/', @string)-2,2),
    Column3 = 'Year: ' + SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('/', @string)+1,2)
```